# whats rootPane or this mean?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

This is my first question

i create a puzzle game with java :

```
public class ImageJoorichin extends JApplet implements KeyListener {

Image myImage,alaki;

boolean preViewImage = true; // Control First PreView before Shuffle

int n, // bord higth & wight
    blankX, // Blank X Coordinates
    blankY; // Blank Y Coordinates

int[][] board;

public void init() {

    myImage = getImage( getCodeBase(), "Screen Shot 1391-12-22 at 12.54.54 PM.png" );

    String temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, "Enter Size of Board", "Board Size", 2);

    n = Integer.parseInt( temp );

    board = new int[ n ][ n ];

    temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, "1-Easy\n2-Normal\n3-Hard", "Level Defficulty", 2);

    int alaki = Integer.parseInt( temp ),
        numberOfShuffle = 0;

    switch( alaki ) {

        case 1:
            numberOfShuffle = n * n;
            break;

        case 2:
            numberOfShuffle = n * n * n;
            break;

        case 3:
            numberOfShuffle = n * n * n * n;
            break;
    }

    repaint();

    set();

    setSize( 400, 400 );

    shuffle( numberOfShuffle );

    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    this.addKeyListener(this);

}

public void start() {

    //repaint();
}

// For New Set & Orginaze Table
public void set() {

    blankX = blankY = n - 1;

    for( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) {

        for( int j = 0; j < board[ i ].length; j++ ) {

                board[ i ][ j ] = ( i * n ) + j;
        }
    }
}

public void right() {

    if( blankY < n - 1 ) {

        board[ blankX ][ blankY ] = board[ blankX ][ blankY + 1 ];
        //board[ blankX ][ blankY - 1 ] = 0;
        ++blankY;
    }      
}

public void left() {

    if( blankY > 0 ) {

        board[ blankX ][ blankY ] = board[ blankX ][ blankY - 1 ];
        //board[ blankX + 1 ][ blankY ] = 0;
        --blankY;
    }      
}

public void down() {

    if( blankX < n - 1 ) {

        board[ blankX ][ blankY ] = board[ blankX + 1 ][ blankY ];
        //board[ blankX ][ blankY - 1 ] = 0;
        ++blankX;
    }      
}

public void up() {

    if( blankX > 0 ) {

        board[ blankX ][ blankY ] = board[ blankX - 1 ][ blankY ];
        //board[ blankX ][ blankY - 1 ] = 0;
        --blankX;
    }      
}

public void shuffle( int numberOfShuffels ) {

    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfShuffels; i++ ) {

        int temp = ( int )( Math.random() * 4 ) + 1;

        switch( temp ) {

            case 1:
                up();
                break;

            case 2:
                down();
                break;

            case 3:
                left();
                break;

            case 4:
                right();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}

public void paint( Graphics graphic ) {

    super.paint( graphic );

    myImage.getWidth( rootPane );

    int distance = getWidth() / n;

    if( preViewImage == true ) { 

        graphic.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 400, 400, this);
        //graphics.drawLine( 0, 0, 100, 100 );


        preViewImage = false; 

        return;
    }

    else {
        for( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) {

            for( int j = 0; j < board[ i ].length; j++ ) {

                int temp = board[ i ][ j ];

                int I = temp / n; // SX
                int J = temp % n; // SY

                graphic.drawImage( myImage, j * distance, i * distance, ( j + 1 ) * distance, ( i + 1 ) * distance, J * distance, I * distance, ( J + 1 ) * distance, ( I + 1 ) * distance, this );

                if( ! won() ) {

                    graphic.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    graphic.drawRect( j * distance, i * distance, distance, distance);
                }
            }
        }

        graphic.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        graphic.fillRect( blankY * distance, blankX * distance, distance, distance);

        if( !won() ) {

            graphic.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            graphic.drawRect( blankY * distance, blankX * distance, distance, distance);
        }

        else {

            graphic.setFont( new Font( "Tohama", Font.BOLD, 27) );
            graphic.setColor(Color.RED);
            int temp = ( getWidth() - graphic.getFontMetrics().stringWidth( "Congratulation" ) ) / 2;
            graphic.drawString( "Congratulation", temp, getHeight() / 2 );
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {}

@Override
public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ) {}

@Override
public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {

    switch( e.getKeyCode() ) {

        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            up();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            down();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            left();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            right();
            break;   
    }

    if( won() ) {

        this.removeKeyListener( this );
    }

    repaint();
}

public boolean won() { 
    for( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) { 

        for( int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++ ) { 

            if( ( i != blankX || j != blankY ) && board[ i ][ j ] != i * n + j ) { 

                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    return true; 
}
```

}

i try to show a preview of image before shuffle that.

but i can't!
i try to do it with `graphic.drawImage()`, but it doesnt show...
but the code is working because if i replace it with `graphic.drawLine()` it will be work

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). You should NOT be ovrriding the paint() method of the JApplet. The tutorial also has a section on "How to Make Applets" you should look at.

Comment: Looks like you make assumption on how and when the paint method will be invoked: paint can be called many times depending on random factors over which you don't have and will never have control. Moreover, consider extending JComponent and override `paintComponent` to perform custom painting (if you just need to draw an image, then use `new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myImage))` and add it to hierarchy).

Comment: @ Guillaume Polet thanks! i got it...